# Maximum Likelihood Estimation of Gamma Function

Tags: statistics

$X_1$, $X_2$, ... , $Xn$ are a sample from Gamma(3, $\theta$)

Find the MLE of $\theta$

How does 1/$\Gamma$(3) $\theta$ $^3$ xi$^2$e^(-$\theta*x_i$) turn into ln((1/2)$^n$) + ln($\theta$ ^ 3n) + $\sum$ln($X_i$ ^ 2) + $\sum(-\theta*X_i$)?

And also, how do I calculate the derivative of ln((1/2)$^n$) + ln($\theta$ ^ 3n) + $\sum$ln($X_i$ ^ 2) + $\sum(-\theta*X_i$)?

Answer (score 1):

If $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. $\Gamma(3,\theta)$ distributed for some $\theta>0$, then $X_i$ has density 
$$
f_{X_i}(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(3)}\theta^3x^2\exp(-\theta x),\quad x>0,
$$
for $i=1,\ldots,n$. Suppose $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ are realizations of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$. Then by independence, the likelihood function is
$$
L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^n f_{X_i}(x_i)=\Gamma(3)^{-n}\theta^{3n}\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^n\exp(-\theta x_i)\right).
$$
The next step is to compute the log-likelihood function $l(\theta)=\log L(\theta)$ using the property that $\log(a\cdot b)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ several times.

Note also that $\Gamma(3)=2!=2$ and hence $\Gamma(3)^{-n}=\left(\frac12\right)^n$.